# How to send message to Facebook channel in Postman using botframework

Tags: c#, facebook, postman, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to send message to Facebook Channel in botframework from Postman, but I'm receiving 403 forbidden. It works perfectly with Facebook but I need to send some message directly to the Bot Facebook channel, like I do in direct line channel.

I've try this endpoint: `https://facebook.botframework.com/api/v1/bots/{{BOTNAME}}` but it always return a 403.

[Update]

Authorization: Bearer {{TOKEN}}

Content-Type: application/json

Body:

```
{
  "text": "test",  
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "type": "message",
  "channelId": "facebook",
  "from": {
    "id": "0123456789",
    "name": "User-1234",
    "role": "user"}
}
```

[image]

[Update 2]

Facebook messenger conversation that I need to send one message from external source.

[image]

Comment: So how are you sending the request? How will we be able to help you if we don't know what you are doing?

Comment: I inserted the body request and header in this topic update. Now you can see my request. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to message the bot or Facebook? What's the goal?

Comment: Yes that's my goal, message the Bot. I can do this in direct line channel.

Comment: Then why not use the Direct Line channel to message the bot? Or message the bot from Facebook?

Comment: Direct Line channel can't send message to the same conversation in facebook, they are different channels. I need to send a message to the same conversation from a webhook to the conversation that facebook started.

Comment: Why though? What are you trying to accomplish by doing that? I don't believe you can use the Facebook channel to message the bot like Direct Line. If you tell us what your goal is, you may get an alternative method.

Comment: I created a webhook to external message because there is no card with password input type, so my external login web site use password input (example: ******) and send all information to the Bot in web channel ormy custom channel "whatsapp".

Comment: I don't follow. You want to redirect to whatsapp?

Comment: No, I need to send a message from external source like Webhook to the same conversation that facebook Started. I edited my post with the chat in Facebook messenger picture.

Comment: That conversation is only between Facebook and the bot though. I don't believe you can accomplish this. If you could, it would be a potential security hole.